# Filter rows from table 1 with table 2 info

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables. One table listing results of a run and a 2nd table with timestamps.

table1 (not sure how to add another column to the table but table 1 has an end time also that will need to be filtered out):

| Tenant | start |
| --- | --- |
| x | 2022-05-01 23:00:00 |
| x | 2022-05-02 02:00:00 |
| x | 2022-05-02 06:00:00 |

table 2:

| start | end |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-05-01 23:00:00 | 2022-05-02 03:00:00 |

The goal is to filter out/ exlude rows from table 1 that fall in between start/end time from table 2.

The results should be :

| Tenant | start |
| --- | --- |
| x | 2022-05-02 06:00:00 |

I tried doing below:

```sql
select *
from table 1
where start not in (select start from table 2)
```

But does not seem to work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using exists logic we can try:

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM table2 t2
    WHERE t1.start BETWEEN t2.start AND t2.end
);
```

For your updated requirement, we could select an exists boolean expression:

```sql
SELECT t1.*, NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM table2 t2
    WHERE t1.start BETWEEN t2.start AND t2.end
) AS mw
FROM table1 t1;
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, if I wanted to modify the query rather than excluding the row can I create another column that has mw if it falls in between the start and end time?